# Can we find the first n fibobacci numbers in logn time?

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

I know that we can get nth fibonacci number in logn time...but it skips some of the numbers to get nth in quick time. My doubt is,can we get **first n** fibonacci numbers in logn time?

Comment: If you have to compute and store _n_ numbers, you have a lower bound of ϴ(n), right? And that's just a lower bound: true time and storage bounds must take into account the number of _digits_, not the number of numbers.

Answer (score 4):

No, because simply outputting *n* numbers can never take less than *O*(*n*) time.